# How to create a Sub Folder into an existing folder?

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

When my Windows Form Loads it run the following code 
`Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E"));`
Which therefor create a folder with the name "F.U.T.U.R.E" Inside MyDocuments Directory. Now I would like to create another Folder when I press on a button inside the existing folder "F.U.T.U.R.E" .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Create Sub Folder into My.Documents."F.U.T.U.R.E"
}
```

Can anyone help me with the codes.

Comment: So what is preventing you from doing it similarily using the same `Directory.CreateDirectory` method?

Comment: Am getting lost , am newbie in programming :) Some help would be welcome.

Comment: before asking google it, this question was already answered at SO many times

Comment: Sorry , Ive search may be my question was not clear on google. Sorry

Comment: @ShekharPankaj Vote to close as duplicate then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way is to use the `DirectoryInfo` that gets returned from that original `CreateDirectory` call, and use the `CreateSubdirectory` method on it to do as needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

So:

```
var directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E"));

directoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory("MySubFolder");
```

However, there are a fair few ways to achieve this so don't take this as the defacto way to do it. Personally I never even realised the `CreateSubdirectory` method even existed, I've always done it by building the URLs and calling the `CreateDirectory` method. Learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: True, that's what I was searching for thanks for the help and yea Ive learn something really important with your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "F.U.T.U.R.E");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);//Create parent folder
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, "YourSubFolderPath"));//Create subfolder same way
```

Comment: Please comment your answer with some explanations.